# Adicionar no título do produto a categoria pai do produto cadastrado

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Pessoal como eu pego a categoria pai de um produto cadastrado, como por ex:

```
Categoria Pai
  -categoria filho 1
    -produto cadastrado 1
    -produto cadastrado 2
  -categoria filho 2
  -categoria filho 3
```

Estou usando um webhook no meu functions.php, ele mostra as categorias mas não sendo a categoria pai o primeiro a aparecer, pois acho que devido ser em ordem alfábetica ele faz isso. Segue o code:

```
  // adiciona no titulo a categoria do produto
  function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
      while (!empty($product_cats)) {
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

      }
     } 
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 2 );
```

Tem como mostrar apenas a categoria pai? 
Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: Põe a estrutura da sua tabela de categorias para ajudar. Mas tentando antecipar, caso a sua tabela de categorias tenha auto-relacionamentos, basta no seu "SELECT" de categorias você buscar apenas aquelas que tenham a chave estrangeira (auto-relacionamento) em branco (null)

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que a *Categoria Pai* seja a categoria mais alta na hierarquia (i.e., ela própria não tem um pai), um método que busque a mais alta na hierarquia resolve o seu problema. Algo como

```
function get_top_categoria($term_id, $taxonomy){

    $pai = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);

    while ($pai->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $pai->parent;

        $pai  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $pai;
}
```

Uma vez definida essa função, você pode alterar o seu método `wpa89819_wc_single_product()` para:

```
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $categorias_pai = array();

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
        foreach($product_cats as $product_cat){
             $top_pai= get_top_categoria( $term->term_id, 'work_type' );
             if(!in_array($top_pai, $categorias_pai){
                 $categorias_pai = $top_pai;
             }
        }
    }

    //Aqui você tem o array com as categorias, e constrói o HTML como quiser
    foreach($categorias_pai as $categoria){
       //....
    }
}
```

Fiz um teste simples aqui, e a idéia é basicamente essa. Você tem que adaptar apenas para a sua lógica.

[Fonte](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92079/get-only-parent-terms-from-wp-get-post-terms)

Comment: Caio ainda não testei sua solução, pois acabei encontrando uma outra maneira de fazer o que eu quero e irei postar agora. Agradeço pelo seu tempo e ainda hoje estarei fazendo um teste com sua solução. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Depois de conversar com algumas pessoas que trabalham com WP chegamos a uma solução que me agradou e irei compartilhar com vocês. Agradeço quem tirou um tempo para analisar essa minha necessidade e de alguma forma tentou ajudar. Segue a solução:

```
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

  $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
   $cat_filha = array();
   $cat_pai = array();
   if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
      while (!empty($product_cats)) {
         $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
         if ($single_cat->parent){
             $cat_filha[] = $single_cat->name;
         } else {
             $cat_pai[] = $single_cat->name;
        }
      }
      ?>
    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><?php echo $cat_pai[0]; ?></h2>
    <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php echo $cat_filha[0]?></h1>
    <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 2 );
```